# vue2-autocomplete-js does not work as mentioned in documentation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have Vue version 2.9.3.

I am trying to get names from a REST API URL:
`http://192.168.1.3/api/clinic/patients?q=s`

will return name of patients starting with `S`.

It by default takes `q` as parameter see [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-autocomplete-js#props)

And following the docs I implemented it like shown below:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="alignLabel">
      <label for="patientName">
        <span>Patient Name <span class="required">*</span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <autocomplete
      url="http://192.168.1.3/api/clinic/patients"
      anchor="title"
      label="writer"
      :on-select="getData">
    </autocomplete>
  </div>
</template>
```

and in script:

```js
var $ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
import Vue from 'vue'
import Autocomplete from 'vue2-autocomplete-js';
Vue.use(Autocomplete)
require('vue2-autocomplete-js/dist/style/vue2-autocomplete.css');
export default {
  name: 'Attend',
  data : function (){ },
  components: {
    'vue-datetimepicker': vuedatetimepicker,
    'autocomplete': Autocomplete,
  },
  methods: {
    getData(obj){
        console.log(obj); // this method is never getting called.
    },
```

the `getData` is never getting called. Autocomplete is not working at all.

Comment: Are you selecting one of the options presented? Can you see the requests for your API in your browser's _Network_ console?

Comment: @Phil in the network console I can see request happening for every character I type in!

Comment: Hey, thanks for only answering one of my two questions

Comment: Well I tried `onShouldGetData` as well as `on-select` both doesnt work I tried his live demo link from GitHub repo that too doesnt wrk and I cloned his repo updated my npm still it doesnt work. I think the problem is not on my end , Does the live demo example work for you : https://rawgit.com/BosNaufal/vue2-autocomplete/master/index.html

Comment: No because he's trying to use the Google Maps API without a key. You still haven't answered my question though... **Are you selecting one of the options presented?**

Comment: What exactly you mean by "one of the options presented"?

Comment: I got some progress, it works, the getData function gets called because I can see console.log print. but sometime it doesnt work, there is not error.