# Using jQuery plugin in Vue.js single file component

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to use [this](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#entry-examples) jQuery plugin in my Vue.js single file component.

as required in the linked autocomplete plugin I imported references in `index.html`, for them to be available all other vue components where I need to use `autocomplete` feature in `input field` .

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

But when I include below code in the script tag of my single file component.

```
 $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
    });
```

I get error console saying:

```
> TypeError: $("#autocomplete").autocomplete is not a function. (In
> '$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
>     source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"] })', '$("#autocomplete").autocomplete' is undefined)
```

But I have included the dependencies in `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

> Solution: use a component as a wrapper

Check out the tutorial here:
https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

Comment: ;( the first line says : 

> It's not a great idea to use jQuery and Vue.js in the same UI. Don't do it if you can avoid it. secondly I get error at the time of instantiation

Comment: Yeah i don't recommend using jquery in Vue.js either, if you just want a autocomplete feature there are plenty of components out there. 
For example this https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-autocomplete-js

Comment: I have tried in the first attempt and that didn't worked at all, I also [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53949995/3311276) vie-single-select that had problem you cannot enter new item not in list

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of js files/script inside your html. It's possible that the Vue script is executed before jQuery is loaded. Move jQuery-related script tags above Vue script tags. You can also safely check if jQuery is available in your Vue script by checking for existence of `window.$`:

```
if (typeof window.$ === 'function') {
  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
    });
}
```

Comment: well if it was the case of jQuery not loading up then I might have go terror at `$("#autocomplete")` but I am getting error `.autocomplete `

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Yes, my mistake not noticing that. However, I cannot recreate your issue in CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/74wy254mx0. If you can provide more detail of how you implement your Vue component with jQuery UI I might find something.

Comment: thank you @blaz that would be great if you can please have a look I have uploaded my project to [codebase](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/sanfx/clinic/)

Comment: I was using eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker component that was causing the problems so I got rid of it and used vue-datetime component then after 4 days of hard work, I finally succeeded adding jQuery based autocomplete working perfectly but my form had a second input field that required same feature and i realised even if we have different id setup for two different input field it resets the old one. so I can only use 1 input field with feature of autocomplete.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz sorry I cannot figure out what is wrong with your code. Even in main.js, `autocomplete` is not defined while in my demo it is there.

Comment: in your vue app, add this npm package: `eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker` yours will stop working.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest u not to use Jquery in Vue. Its bad practice. There is a number of vue plugins u can use and even create your own (which is best option IMHO)

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-autocomplete-js
    https://github.com/paliari/v-autocomplete
    https://vuejsexamples.com/tag/autocomplete/
    https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-autocomplete-component/`

Comment: I agree with you , but right now I am short of time, and yesterday night I stayed up late to get things working using jQuery